# F# int.MaxValue is "not a valid constant expression," but System.Int32.MaxValue is?

Tags: .net, f#, data-annotations

**TL;DR:** the F# compiler interprets `int` in this context as the [`int` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370576.aspx), as [determined by Eugene Fotin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20271777/230390) and [expanded upon by Gene Belitski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20273189/230390). The best workaround is to use `System.Int32.MaxValue` or a unique type alias as described below.

---

Consider the following record type:

```ml
type User = {
    Username : string
}
```

I want `Username` to be at least three characters long, so I use the `StringLength` attribute. There is no maximum length, so I set it to `int.MaxValue`:

```ml
type User = {
    [<StringLength(int.MaxValue, MinimumLength=3)>]
    Username : string
}
```

This gives me the following error:

> This is not a valid constant expression or custom attribute value.

Everything is peachy if I use `System.Int32` instead:

```ml
type User = {
    [<StringLength(System.Int32.MaxValue, MinimumLength=3)>]
    Username : string
}
```

It also compiles if I alias `int`:

```ml
type User = {
    [<StringLength(num.MaxValue, MinimumLength=3)>]
    Username : string
}
and num = int
```

Or fully qualify the type:

```ml
type User = {
    [<StringLength(Microsoft.FSharp.Core.int.MaxValue, MinimumLength=3)>]
    Username : string
}
```

I checked in the F# source and [`int` is defined exactly as you would expect](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/19507b98bc6a7995e9c19c40f044fdfeb578ef77/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types-prelude.fs):

```ml
type int32 = System.Int32
// Then, a few lines later…
type int = int32
```

What's going on? I assumed that F# primitive types were interchangeable with other types in most contexts, but it looks like something is missing from my mental model.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's how F# type inference works in different contexts with different syntactic entities coincidentally having the same name, which in case of `int` may be any of:

- function `int:'T->int` of full name `Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.int`
- `type int = int32` of full name `Microsoft.FSharp.Core.int`
- `type int<'Measure> = int` of full name `Microsoft.FSharp.Core.int<_>`

One way to demo this workings would be the following scenario: if we just enter

```
int;;
```

in FSI we'll get something like

```
val it : (int -> int) = <fun:it@3>
```

in other words, it's a function that cannot have `MaxValue` property associated with it:

```
> int.MaxValue;;

int.MaxValue;;
----^^^^^^^^

... error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'MaxValue' is not defined
```

The same would apply to `int32`, which, when being used in a context of expression is inferred by FSI as just another function with signature `(int -> int32)`.

Now when it comes to

```
type num = int
```

in this context `int` is inferred to be a type name abbreviation for `System.Int32`, so `num` is a type abbreviation as well, but now name ambiguity does not have place, so `num.MaxValue` is inferred exactly what we expect it to be, giving in FSI

```
> num.MaxValue;;
val it : int = 2147483647
```

Finally, when you use `Microsoft.FSharp.Core.int` you explicitly refer to the type entity, there is no place for ambiguity, so it works as expected.

Back to your use case with attribute parameter - in this context `int` is treated by type inference as part of expression to deliver argument value, i.e. as function, unless you explicitly or indirectly set another interpretation.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like compiler treating `int` in an attribute's parameter as a conversion function [`int`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370576.aspx).

Comment: You're right, that's what's going on. I wonder why that is? Something in the F# grammar, I guess?